# Seperate tab to diffrence class in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

When I using tab in WPF and I create few tab , my class file became to big code and uncleare.

I there any way to seperate that each tab woll be in diffrent class?

Or is there another smart way to orginize code as well?

Comment: You can use `partial` class to seperating to different class file

Comment: I know, file name need to be same name as class name, and if I seperate files with `partial`  all of them will be same names(or maybe class_part1.cs class_part2.cs and that strange)

Comment: In C#, the class name can be diff from file name. You can name each file name to match the tab name, or something like `mainclassname.tabname.cs`

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate views/usercontrols in each of the tabs. In this way, each tab will have their separate business logic.